# Is there a method like intent.putextra of Android for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, android-intent

I'm programming an App in both languages: Android & iOS, but I'm trying to find a way to use a similar method to move data from a ViewController to another, like Intent on Android does it. My code on Android is:

At the Activity that is sending the data:

```
  public void goToUserScreen(UserModel userM) {
        userModel = userM;
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("USER_MODEL", userModel);
        intent.putExtra("LOGIN_MODEL", loginModel);
        intent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_MODEL", notificationModel);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

The Activity that is receiving:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        loginModel =            (LoginModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("LOGIN_MODEL");
        notificationModel =     (NotificationModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("NOTIFICATION_MODEL");
        userModel =             (UserModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("USER_MODEL");
```

Does someone know how to do it on iOS? By the way, for iOS I'm programming on Xcode 8, so can somebody help me to solve this with Swift3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extras` in an intent is just a map of `Parcelable` values. In iOS you can pass `NSDictionary` to your `UIViewController` and then parse it with similar effect. Like so:

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
viewControllerB.intentDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

Then in ViewControllerB:

```
LoginModel *loginModel = [intentDictionary objectForKey:"LOGIN_MODEL"];
NotificationModel *notificationModel = [intentDictionary objectForKey:"NOTIFICATION_MODEL"];
UserModel *userModel = [intentDictionary objectForKey:"USER_MODEL"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it really solve my issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: By the way, do you know how to do this on Swift 3? Because I didn't fin any information about this on Swift 3, I only found on Objective-C. Help Please!